# Как сделать так, чтобы вёрстка не ломалась при отсутствии картинки или неверной ссылке на неё?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, img

```css
.home_subscribe {
    background: #DFEEB6;
    margin-top: 160px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}

.home_subscribe .col_left .thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

.home_subscribe .wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 450px;
}

.home_subscribe .col_left,
.home_subscribe .col_right {
    width: calc(50% - 35px);
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}

.home_subscribe .col_right .box_title {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}

.home_subscribe .col_right .subtitle {
    color: #F7A1A8;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.home_subscribe .col_right {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <section class="home_subscribe svg_style">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="col_left">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="img/menu2.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col_right">
            <h2 class="box_title">Natural Smoothies</h2>
            <span class="subtitle">Drink natural to be stronger</span>
            <form class="subscribe" action="index.html" method="POST">
             <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Your email">
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Subscribe">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Она и так не ломается. Непонятно, в чём проблема

Comment: Вероятно, нужно задать CSS-правила для размеров или пропорций картинки, чтобы её загрузка не влияла на задуманную сетку верстки (и не приводила к _пересчету лейаута_). Такие как width, height, min-width, max-width, object-fit, aspect-ratio и пр. Зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: сейчас добавлю сам код

Comment: Я запустил ваш код и не увидел ничего сломанного. В чём проблема-то? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnw6q.png

Comment: С картинкой он выглядит точно так же ужасно, поэтому я всё равно не понимаю вашу проблему https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wQk7.png

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы всё выглядело красиво — значит напишите такие стили, которые будут выглядеть красиво. При чём тут картинка вообще? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Битые картинки можно тоже оформлять.

```css
img {
     display: inline-block;
     font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
     font-weight: 300;
     line-height: 2;
     text-align: center;
     min-width: 300px;
     min-height: 50px;
     position: relative;
}
img:before {
     content: '';
     width: 100%;
     height: calc(100% + 10px);
     background-color: #ccc;
     border-radius: 10px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: -2px;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
img:after {
     content: "\2639" " " attr(alt);
     font-size: 18px;
     color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
     top: 5px;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="/битая_картинка.jpg" alt="Картинка">
```

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

img:after {
  content: "\2639" " " attr(alt);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<img src="/битая_картинка.jpg" alt="Картинка">
```